# Is there a way to run the optimiser over a for loop?

Tags: python, scipy

I am doing portfolio optimization. I have the following code:

```
def objective(weights):
    return -np.sum(rets.T*weights)
```

where rets is a list of returns imported from bloomberg

```
def max_volatility(weights):
    vol = min_volatilty  - np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights)))
    return vol

opts_vol = sco.minimize(objective, list_initial_weights, bounds = bnds, method = 'SLQSP', constraints = cons)
```

Currently the program runs for one value of min_volatility but I want it to run over the range of values in parameters:

```
parameters = np.linspace(8,10,20)
```

I want the program to give me a new list of weights for each point in parameters using optimization.

How can I do this?

Comment: Iterate over the parameters!  `minimize` only gives you one set weights.

Comment: Do you mean run the entire program in a loop? I tried that and I get the same solution for all the cases.